# How to do an inter-type injection on classes that have methods with a certain annotation?

Tags: android, aspectj

To give you some context:
I am successfully using aspectJ with android projects, and I've written a `@Background` annotation that I apply to methods that cannot block the main UI thread.
This annotation is being intercepted by a pointcut and an around advice that takes care of running the code in a background thread and dealing with network errors and user notification.

What I would like to do next is to automatically provide a reload button on the menu to all activities that have such background methods
This has to be done by overriding a method with the following signature:
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu);

Activities that don't do background stuff don't need to have menu, and thus, don't override that method.

So, is there a way to make aspectJ override a method in just those classes that have (at least) a method with a particular annotation ?

Or is there a more elegant solution ?

Thanks,
Carlos.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `hasMethod` type pattern (you can see the [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=86818) for usages). You should be able to add a marker interface to your types that have the method(s) with the required signature and then introduce onCreateOptionsMenu to it.

Comment: Thanks @ramnivas. This looks like it could be useful but there are 2 problems: 1) this feature was requested 7 years ago and as been delayed several times and is still not in the latest milestone release from what I read in the changelogs 2) Using a Marker Interface pattern implies that the Inter-type injection would be done on the interface. If that is the case, I don't see how I could call other methods that have been declared on the Activity superclass that all activities extend... As a workaround I used a declare parent pattern and have the classes extend one that has overriden that method